# Common custom server side validation function for multiple aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple aspx pages which have same form controls taking user inputs like firstname, lastname, address.

These fields already have required, regex and length based client side validations. Now what I need to do is add a custom validator to these pages which will perform a common validation. But I dont want to go about editing all the pages as they are in hundreds. I am only looking at adding a custom validation tag to the aspx pages and a common server side validation function which can be assigned to the custom validator tag on the aspx pages, which will save my efforts.

These pages are very old so I cannot change the form to a user control. Also because each page has different css.

Is it possible to write a common server side validator function which can be accessed by multiple aspx pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own Validator by extending the CustomValidator class like this

```
namespace CustomValidation
{
    public class MyValidator : CustomValidator
    {
        protected override bool OnServerValidate(string value)
        {
            bool baseresult = base.OnServerValidate(value);
            if (baseresult && value == "TestValue")
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
        }

        protected override bool ControlPropertiesValid()
        {
            return base.ControlPropertiesValid();
        }

        protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
        {
            return base.EvaluateIsValid();
        }
    }
}
```

And in your aspx pages just add the control -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mytag" Namespace="CustomValidation" Assembly="WebApplication1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <mytag:MyValidator ErrorMessage="Testing" ControlToValidate="txtBox" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBox"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button Text="Test Button" runat="server" ID="btnTest" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And your OnServerValidate will be called on Page.IsValid

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes this does what I need to do.

Comment: Good to know that .